# Why is my request taking longer to complete than EXPLAIN tells it is taking?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on optimizing a SQL request by creating indexes.

After a few tweaks I could divide the request completion time from 600ms to 200ms approximatively.

Yet, EXPLAIN on PgAdmin tells me my request only takes 5.9ms in top level inclusive time.

Am I reading it wrong?

SQL Query (generated by TypeORM):

```
SELECT "node"."object_id" AS "node_object_id",
       "node"."node_id" AS "node_node_id",
       "node"."start_rev" AS "node_start_rev",
       "node"."end_rev" AS "node_end_rev",
       "node"."updated_on" AS "node_updated_on",
       "node"."lang" AS "node_lang",
       "node"."second_lang" AS "node_second_lang",
       "node"."title" AS "node_title",
       "node"."title_second_lang" AS "node_title_second_lang",
       "node"."execution_modes" AS "node_execution_modes",
       "node"."circuit_letters" AS "node_circuit_letters",
       "node"."root_id" AS "node_root_id",
       "node"."owner" AS "node_owner",
       "node"."updated_by" AS "node_updated_by",
       "node"."main_skill_code" AS "node_main_skill_code",
       "alias_node_artifact"."root_id" AS "alias_node_artifact_root_id",
       "alias_node_artifact"."current_rev" AS "alias_node_artifact_current_rev",
       "alias_node_artifact"."created_on" AS "alias_node_artifact_created_on",
       "alias_node_artifact"."reference" AS "alias_node_artifact_reference",
       "alias_node_artifact"."ref_group" AS "alias_node_artifact_ref_group",
       "alias_node_artifact"."ref_ata" AS "alias_node_artifact_ref_ata",
       "alias_node_artifact"."ref_seq_number" AS "alias_node_artifact_ref_seq_number",
       "alias_node_artifact"."locked_on" AS "alias_node_artifact_locked_on",
       "alias_node_artifact"."created_by" AS "alias_node_artifact_created_by",
       "alias_node_artifact"."ac_program_id" AS "alias_node_artifact_ac_program_id",
       "alias_node_artifact"."locked_by" AS "alias_node_artifact_locked_by",
       "alias_node_artifact_created_by"."username" AS "alias_node_artifact_created_by_username",
       "alias_node_artifact_created_by"."fullname" AS "alias_node_artifact_created_by_fullname",
       "alias_node_artifact_ac_program"."id" AS "alias_node_artifact_ac_program_id",
       "alias_node_artifact_ac_program"."name" AS "alias_node_artifact_ac_program_name",
       "alias_node_artifact_ac_program"."code" AS "alias_node_artifact_ac_program_code",
       "alias_node_artifact_ac_program"."letter" AS "alias_node_artifact_ac_program_letter",
       "alias_node_artifact_revisions"."object_id" AS "alias_node_artifact_revisions_object_id",
       "alias_node_artifact_revisions"."node_id" AS "alias_node_artifact_revisions_node_id",
       "alias_node_artifact_revisions"."start_rev" AS "alias_node_artifact_revisions_start_rev",
       "alias_node_artifact_revisions"."end_rev" AS "alias_node_artifact_revisions_end_rev",
       "alias_node_artifact_revisions"."status" AS "alias_node_artifact_revisions_status",
       "alias_node_artifact_revisions"."user" AS "alias_node_artifact_revisions_user",
       "alias_node_artifact_revisions"."date" AS "alias_node_artifact_revisions_date",
       "alias_node_artifact_revisions"."root_id" AS "alias_node_artifact_revisions_root_id"
FROM "test_root_node" "node"
LEFT JOIN "test_root_revision_node" "node_target_revision_data" ON "node_target_revision_data".root_id = "node".root_id
AND "node_target_revision_data".start_rev =
  (SELECT current_rev
   FROM "test_root_artifact"
   WHERE root_id = "node".root_id)
LEFT JOIN "test_root_artifact" "alias_node_artifact" ON "alias_node_artifact"."root_id"="node"."root_id"
LEFT JOIN "ext_usr_user" "alias_node_artifact_created_by" ON "alias_node_artifact_created_by"."username"="alias_node_artifact"."created_by"
LEFT JOIN "ext_spf_ac_program" "alias_node_artifact_ac_program" ON "alias_node_artifact_ac_program"."id"="alias_node_artifact"."ac_program_id"
LEFT JOIN "test_root_revision_node" "alias_node_artifact_revisions" ON "alias_node_artifact_revisions"."root_id"="alias_node_artifact"."root_id"
AND (("alias_node_artifact_revisions"."start_rev" <= "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev"
      AND ("alias_node_artifact_revisions"."end_rev" IS NULL
           OR "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev" < "alias_node_artifact_revisions"."end_rev")))
WHERE ("node"."start_rev" <= "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev"
       AND ("node"."end_rev" IS NULL
            OR "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev" < "node"."end_rev"))
  AND "node"."node_id" = '047cfbe3-cba4-4081-9f6a-5e08d51309a7'
```

Plain test EXPLAIN :

```
"Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=19.84..4675.33 rows=95 width=385) (actual time=5.937..5.952 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Join Filter: ((alias_node_artifact_revisions.start_rev <= node_target_revision_data.start_rev) AND ((alias_node_artifact_revisions.end_rev IS NULL) OR (node_target_revision_data.start_rev < alias_node_artifact_revisions.end_rev)))"
"  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 302"
"  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=19.55..4583.48 rows=9 width=303) (actual time=5.411..5.423 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Join Filter: (alias_node_artifact_ac_program.id = alias_node_artifact.ac_program_id)"
"        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=19.55..4582.11 rows=9 width=290) (actual time=5.382..5.392 rows=1 loops=1)"
"              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=19.41..4580.35 rows=9 width=270) (actual time=5.362..5.371 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=19.14..4576.63 rows=9 width=202) (actual time=5.347..5.355 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on test_root_node node  (cost=10.56..585.50 rows=293 width=198) (actual time=0.153..0.883 rows=303 loops=1)"
"                                Recheck Cond: (node_id = '047cfbe3-cba4-4081-9f6a-5e08d51309a7'::uuid)"
"                                Heap Blocks: exact=108"
"                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ""IDX_7f72bf62a1c311336c8c9ea053""  (cost=0.00..10.48 rows=293 width=0) (actual time=0.100..0.101 rows=303 loops=1)"
"                                      Index Cond: (node_id = '047cfbe3-cba4-4081-9f6a-5e08d51309a7'::uuid)"
"                          ->  Index Only Scan using test_root_revision_node_start_rev_end_rev_root_id_idx on test_root_revision_node node_target_revision_data  (cost=8.58..13.61 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=303)"
"                                Index Cond: ((start_rev >= node.start_rev) AND (start_rev = (SubPlan 1)) AND (root_id = node.root_id))"
"                                Filter: ((node.end_rev IS NULL) OR (start_rev < node.end_rev))"
"                                Rows Removed by Filter: 1"
"                                Heap Fetches: 303"
"                                SubPlan 1"
"                                  ->  Index Scan using pk_0a59a848eada13a258968f056b2 on test_root_artifact  (cost=0.27..8.29 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=303)"
"                                        Index Cond: (root_id = node.root_id)"
"                    ->  Index Scan using pk_0a59a848eada13a258968f056b2 on test_root_artifact alias_node_artifact  (cost=0.27..0.41 rows=1 width=68) (actual time=0.008..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                          Index Cond: (root_id = node.root_id)"
"              ->  Index Scan using pk_9c530ad1f37e2a16dcc8cf87377 on ext_usr_user alias_node_artifact_created_by  (cost=0.14..0.20 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                    Index Cond: ((username)::text = (alias_node_artifact.created_by)::text)"
"        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=3 width=13) (actual time=0.019..0.020 rows=1 loops=1)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on ext_spf_ac_program alias_node_artifact_ac_program  (cost=0.00..1.03 rows=3 width=13) (actual time=0.015..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  ->  Index Scan using test_root_revision_node_root_id_idx on test_root_revision_node alias_node_artifact_revisions  (cost=0.29..8.77 rows=96 width=86) (actual time=0.025..0.380 rows=303 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (root_id = alias_node_artifact.root_id)"
```

[image]

Comment: The timings don't really matter. It's the cost and number of rows that matter. `EXPLAIN` won't return the actual data to your client, so any network delays won't be included. The very fact that returning just 95 rows takes 200ms means your query returns too much data

Comment: I am only getting one output row, so you mean that the internal processes of the request are handling too big chunks of data? How can I know what costs means and how can I know what to improve?

Comment: Please use plain text, not images. It looks like your network or application are slow and just 5.9ms is spent in the database

Comment: Updated the question. So this would mean we're having a slow network issue on top of performance issues, I indeed have 150ms for a simple SELECT on a table.

Comment: If the query takes substantially longer than 6 milliseconds, either you are measuring the wrong thing, or it is the network lag, or it is client processing time.

Comment: I think you are confusing timings. The `5.9ms` is the time for the SQL query to run on the server.  The larger number(`200 - 600ms`) is the timing for the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to run and return data back to pgAdmin4.

Comment: Since I'm getting those same times for a query without EXPLAIN / ANAlYLZE, this might be due to network time. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The additional time is the network response time and client processing time.